# Intermittent - Infinite loop detected in JError

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I got an intermittent Infinite loop detected in JError, so I tried to understand the stack error without luck.
I did nothing in my site, no password change and the website works again if I just refresh it.
Does anyone already got this error?

**Error message:**

```
#1 JError::raise(1, 500, Application Instantiation Error, , 1) called at [myWebsite/public_html/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:253]
#2 JError::raiseError(500, Application Instantiation Error) called at [myWebsite/public_html/libraries/joomla/factory.php:50]
#3 JFactory::getApplication() called at [myWebsite/public_html/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:722]
.....
#18 JFactory::_createSession(Array ([name] => 00fab4b94d0fc041e2716c66dd1b1548)) called at [myWebsite/public_html/libraries/joomla/factory.php:103]
#19 JFactory::getSession(Array ([name] => 00fab4b94d0fc041e2716c66dd1b1548)) called at [myWebsite/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:984]
#20 JApplication->_createSession(00fab4b94d0fc041e2716c66dd1b1548) called at [myWebsite/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:135]
#21 JApplication->__construct(Array ([clientId] => 0)) called at [myWebsite/public_html/includes/application.php:48]
#22 JSite->__construct(Array ()) called at [myWebsite/public_html/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:175]
#23 JApplication::getInstance(site, Array (), J) called at [myWebsite/public_html/libraries/joomla/factory.php:53]
#24 JFactory::getApplication(site) called at [myWebsite/public_html/index.php:28]
```

Comment: have you ensured you're running the latest version of Joomla 1.5? (1.5.26)

Comment: Sorry, i'm using Version 1.7.3

Comment: Why are you using Joomla 1.7? Upgrade to Joomla 2.5.14 and see if you still have the same problem. There shouldn't be any compatibility issues so the upgrade should go smoothly.

Comment: :/ i don't think so, but will try.